# Proof verification: If $v$ is a solution for $Bx=0$ if and only if $v$ is a solution for $(AB)x=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Given $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $A$ is invertible, if $v$ is a solution for $Bx=0$ if and only if  $v$ is a solution for $(AB)x=0$

Here is the proof I have come up with:

If $(AB)v\ne0$, the we know that $Av\ne0\wedge Bv\ne0$ causing a contradiction and since $\forall v:Av\ne0$ (A is invertible and therefore it's columns are linearly independent) we get that $(AB)v=0\Rightarrow Bv=0$.

Comment: If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if $A$ is invertible

$$Ay=0 \iff y=0$$

thus

$$(AB)x=0\iff A(Bx)=0\iff Bx=0 \quad \square$$

Comment: While I understand your proof, I am looking for someone to verify mine

Comment: I don’t understand your first implication: “If $(AB)v\ne0$, the we know that $Av\ne0\wedge Bv\ne0$“

Comment: Maybe It should be simply: since A is not singular if $(AB)v\ne0$ then $Bv\ne0$.

Comment: If $(AB)v\ne0$ then we know that its impossible for $(Av)B=(0)B=0$ (same for $A(Bv)=A(0)=0$)